# Dynamically creating controller actions in Rails 5

Tags: swagger, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm trying to set up dynamic routing in a Rails 5.1.4 api.  Originally, I had all my dynamic routes pointing to a single action, which works just fine.  The problem came when I attempted to use the swagger-docs gem, which requires a separate action for each entry in order to generate the necessary json for swagger ui.  So, I figured I could simply dynamically create the methods and point the routes at them.  As far as I can tell, the methods are not being created and I don't understand why.  Even if I drop my debugger into the loop that cycles through my sections, it never gets triggered.  I deeply appreciate any help on this.

routes.rb

```
 Section.active.all.each do |section|
    get "/#{section.url}", :to => "sections##{section.url}", defaults: { id: section.id }
 end
```

sections_controller.rb

```
class SectionsController < ApplicationController
  Section.active.all do |section|
    define_method :"#{section.url}" do
      #some things
    end
  end
end
```

development.rb

```
  config.eager_load = true
```

If I call:

```
SectionsController.action_methods
=> #<Set: {}>
```

Comment: Have you restarted your server (and Spring)?

Comment: Yep, many times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just making the section_url a param, pointing everything to the show action and adding the possible section urls in the docs description.

routes.rb

```
get "/:section_url", to: "sections#show"
#must be at the end of the routes definitions
```

sections_controller.rb

```
swagger_api :show do
  summary "Returns Section Items"
  param :path, :section_url, :string, :required, Section.active.pluck(:url).join(", ")
  response :ok
  response :not_found
end
```